# IronPython 2.7.7: Could not load type 'System.TypeExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.2.0.0

Tags: ironpython

I'm having trouble running some IronPython code in a Visual Studio 2015 C# Console Application project that I've successfully run in a [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) environment. So I assume there's an issue with how I've set up my environment, but I'm having trouble diagnosing the issue.

Here's my code:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            options["Frames"] = true;
            options["FullFrames"] = true;
            //The exception is thrown by the line below
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
            string pyscript = @"";    

            var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(pyscript);
            var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        }
    }
}
```

Python.CreateEngine(options) ends up throwing an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in Microsoft.Scripting.dll
```

Whose inner exception reads:

```
Could not load type 'System.TypeExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral
```

Inner Exception Source:

```
IronPython
```

Inner Exception Stack Trace:

```
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.GetInitialPrefix()
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext..ctor(ScriptDomainManager manager, IDictionary`2 options)
```

This project references IronPython.StdLib (2.7.7), which is using IronPython (2.7.7)

I've used dotPeek to poke around the IronPython related dlls, and can't seem to find anything that references a type named "System.TypeExtensions". I can't seem to find such a type when I google around for it either.

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the difference between my Linqpad environment and my Visual Studio environment is the version of DynamicLanguageRuntime that they were using. Linqpad was using the lowest compatible version of Microsoft.Scripting.dll: 1.1.2, while Visual Studio (via Paket) was using newer version that should have been compatible: 1.2.0.100.l. These version numbers correspond with the nuget version of DynamicLanguageRuntime.

[IronPython 2.7.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython/2.7.7) is supposed to be compatible with DynamicLanguageRuntime (>= 1.1.2), but this doesn't appear to be the case. I'm going to post an issue on the GitHub project. But for the time being, using DynamicLanguageRuntime 1.1.2 is a work around.

Edit: [This appears to be a known issue](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/issues/317).